# How to get informed in metasploit when a user does a reverse shell to my computer

Tags: attacks

I sometimes do reverse shells on metasploit but I'm not sure when my target will actually execute the payload. I would like an alarm of some sort to tell me when he does. this can easily be done in a script.

Is there a way for metasploit to execute a script once he connects to my terminal? I am using that "exploit/multi/handler" thing for the incoming connection.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible have a look at http://www.digininja.org/metasploit/session_created.php it explains how to do it!

Also useful http://seclists.org/metasploit/2010/q1/87

Relevant excerpt from the links in case they ever go down:

> A version of this has been added to trunk, just svn update /
>   msfupdate:
>
> ```
> msf> load sounds
> ```
>
> You can create your own "theme" by copying data/sounds/default/ to
>   data/sounds/mytheme, modifying the files, and then loading the plugin
>   with:
>
> ```
> msf> load sounds theme=mytheme
> ```

---

> I haven't tried the Windows version but from what I've read it should
>   work and most people will have the required gem installed by default.
>   If you don't you can install it with:
>
> ```
> gem install win32-sound
> ```